# Security between Client and RESTful Service

Tags: security, spring-security, ionic2

I have an architectural question I need some advise on.

I currently have a Client written in `Ionic2` with plans to deploy to `iOS`, `Android` and a `Web Browser`.

I have a Tomcat Server running on AWS with `Java8/Spring RESTful Web Services` talking to a `MYSQL` Database.

I am also using `Firebase Authentication`. A user can access the app if they are not signed in, and once signed in have access to more functionality.

So, user data is stored in `Firebase` with a `uid` as key. Corresponding user data is also stored in the `MYSQL` Database.

I am planning to also add a `PayPal` payment Gateway.

**Question**

I am not an expert in Security Architecture. So my question is, what security considerations should I have?

I assume the Payment Gateway will be secure as I will be interacting with the `PayPal` api.

Second, currently the `Ionic2` app communicates with the `Java RESTful Services` via `HTTP`. Should I be securing these Request/Response calls?

With regard to the `RESTful Service` calls, I only transport sensitive information in once call, so would like to secure that. Otherwise there is no sensitive information, but I don't want the app to be subject to any malicious behaviour.

As you can see, this is a pretty open question, but I am looking for guidance on the correct architectural path to follow.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the security considerations, OWASP(Open Web Application Security Project) provides a very good direction for REST services [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet). It might seem overwhelming looking at it for the first time but it is upto you how deeply you want to implement them depending on the sensitivity of the information in your APIs and impact if someone exploits the vulnerabilities in your APIs.

However, I would recommend using HTTPS rather than HTTP for all your APIs.

Answer (score 1):

if it is Spring based Application, then i recommend to go for Spring JWT(Json Web Token).